# .net core based application on IIS - Page not found multiple file extensions

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404

I have a windows server 2019 (1809) with IIS 10
.net core 3.1.13 hosting + shared framework were installed.
dev team are developing their API application under a website on that server. they installed swagger as well.
when browsing to https://ipaddress/swagger im successfully receiving the swagger api page.

problem:
I created an .aspx file with dummy text(for monitoring purposes using F5 BIGIP). however when I browse from inside/outside the server to that page it is not found 404 even though **it is there!**

```
This 172.10.10.10 page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://172.10.10.10/f5.html
HTTP ERROR 404
```

I also tried other file formats *.txt* or even *.html* but those are also not found.
I verified that file extension is correct.
in **Request Filtering** none of the file extensions mentioned is there. also didnt see anything suspicious in [hidden segments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Go6m.jpg) tab.

appreciate any help please

Comment: update: when I use the default website on that server, all file extensions are displaying fine.

Comment: Most likely a problem of permissions on your chosen folder.

Comment: doesnt look like that. all permissions are the same as default website folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after more digging, this looks like a built in inability of .net core applications.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/serving-static-files

Host static files in ASP.NET Core
It may be surprising, but **ASP.NET Core doesn't have built-in support for static files.**
This feature that has always existed as just a part of ASP.NET, enabled by IIS, isn't intrinsic to ASP.NET Core or its Kestrel web server. To serve static files from an ASP.NET Core app, you must configure static files middleware.